# creating rss link for podcast doesnt seem to be working for itunes

Tags: rss

I copying the sample rss from http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html
and pasting it to my html file to test but itune say the Fixing iTunes “does not seem to be a valid podcast URL” errors
Heres the link

Can someone help me please....
This feed is valid, but interoperability with the widest range of feed readers could be improved by implementing the following recommendations.

```
Feeds should not be served with the "text/html" media type [help]


Your feed appears to be encoded as "UTF-8", but your server is reporting "iso-8859-1" [help]


line 15, column 35: Email address is missing real name [help]

        <webMaster>joti.chand@gmail.com</webMaster>
                                       ^

line 18, column 4: iTunes elements should only be present in feeds encoded as UTF-8 [help]

        <itunes:author>joti.chand@gmail.com</itunes:author>
        ^

line 55, column 0: Missing atom:link with rel="self" [help]

    </channel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps pasting it to an HTML file to test isn't the right tack? Why not .xml file?